# What limits the maximum reaction force that can be exerted by the table?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

Suppose I have an object placed on a table which exerts a force $$W=mg$$ on the table. The table provides a reaction force which is $-mg$ if the table does not accelerate.  However if the table breaks, the reaction force will be less than $-mg$. My question is what limits the maximum reaction force that can be exerted by the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight of the object makes the table deflect (bend) slightly. This stretches the inter-molecular bonds in the table. The inter-molecular bonds resist the deflection, and this gives rise to the normal force exerted by the table on the object. However, the inter-molecular bonds have a finite strength, and if they are stretched too much they will break, and the table will no longer be able to support the object.

The whole story is a bit more complicated than this, because most materials are actually much weaker in bulk than the strength of their inter-molecular bonds suggests they should be. This is because stress tends to be concentrated in certain points instead of being spread uniformly throughout the material. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_concentration) for more details.